# Check file, always return true

Tags: java, android

I tried the code below and if I rename the music-file `Musik_stk100.mp3` the if still returns true?

What am I doing wrong?

```
String filepath = "file:///mnt/sdcard/data/musikapp/";
final File musicfile = new File(filepath  + "/" + "Musik_stk100.mp3");
final ImageView imagetrue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagetrue);
final ImageView imagefalse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefalse);

    if (musicfile.exists()){
        imagetrue .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imagefalse .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        imagefalse .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imagetrue .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

**SOLUTION**

```
String filepath = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/musikapp/");
final File musicfile = new File(filepath  + "Musik_stk100.mp3");
final ImageView imagetrue = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagetrue);
final ImageView imagefalse = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagefalse);

    if (musicfile.exists()){
        imagetrue .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imagefalse .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        imagefalse .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imagetrue .setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Comment: You should be getting error, you have declared `imagetrue` and used `imageTrue` and same for other ImageView, btw, this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: First, Java I/O, like `File`, does not use the `file://` URL prefix. Second, **never hardcode paths**. `/mnt/sdcard` will be wrong on many devices. Use appropriate methods to get at locations on external storage, such as `getExternalFilesDir()` and `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

Comment: CommonsWare - do you wanna answer question? It was he answer i was looking for :)

Comment: what does musicfile.isFile() return?  I have to also agree with the other folks, I don't see how that file path will work.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, not as an edit to the question :)